# Why am I getting a syntax error with my Shell arithmetic?

Tags: shell

I have a problem with a linux shell script (`sh`).

I'm trying to write a script that calculates combinations, but I think I get overflows when
trying to calculate faculties. So, I'm trying another technique. In this technique I used this:

```
a=`expr $var1 \* $var2 / $var3`
```

This is giving errors, and apperently, I can't do this:

```
a=`expr ($var1 \* $var2) / $var3`
```

because this gives errors as well.

How do I do it?

Comment: What errors are you getting? That works in bash at least

Comment: expr: syntax error

Answer (score 6):

You can use `dc` for arbitrary precision results:

```
precision=4 var1=3 var2=4 var3=5
a=`echo "$precision k $var1 $var2 * $var3 /p" | dc`
```

should work in about every Unix variant since 1977 or so. If you know you have gnu dc available the more concise

```
a=`dc -e "$precision k $var1 $var2 * $var3 /p"`
```

can be used.

Answer (score 2):

For your example with parens, you must escape them too: `expr \( $var1 + $var2 \) / $var3` (and don't omit the spaces, or `expr` will complain).

In `bash` you can also use built-in arithmetic expansion like this: `echo $(( ($var1+$var2)/$var3 ))`

And for infix calculations there's `bc` (while `dc` is for reverse-polish notation).

Comment: getcombination()
{
tempres=1
a=expr \\( $2 - $1 \\) + 1
b=1
while [ a -le $2 -a b -le $1 ]
do
tempres=expr \\( $tempres \\* a \\) / b
a=`expr $a + 1`
b=`expr $b + 1`
done
echo $tempres
} This still gives expr errors....

Comment: Could you please use pastebin or similar service to post the exact offending code (preferably, the bare minimum of it needed to reproduce your problem)?  I'm having hard time de-crypting what you put in this comment.

Comment: @3sdmx: just don't bother with `expr`, use the shell arithmetic `$((…))` instead. @alex: `$((…))` isn't specific to bash, it's in POSIX.